# New Mac Machine is asking apple id

Tags: macos, apple-id

New Mac Machine is asking apple id on start up of machine is it really required or mandatory to have an apple id to start with this? if so can i create an apple id without providing any credit card info?.
Please guide this newbe...

Comment: Why not call their customer support? You bought their product, they should fix it for you.

Comment: You cannot create an apple ID without putting in your card details. However I believe you shouldn't need to put one in, in order to log in.

Comment: @geminiCoder You can create an Apple ID ***without*** entering any credit card information, see http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534.

Comment: To avoid people telling you to press the skip button, please edit in some more details on what exactly you don't get about this one form on setting up OS X. (You will also find that reading the guide on [ask] and sticking to one question per question works best on the Stack Exchange sites.)

Comment: The article on how to create an Apple ID without supplying a credit card is common to iOS and Mac OS X, so I'll point you there and you can feel free to edit this to reopen it if you find the answers here aren't what you sought.

Answer (score 5):

The AppleID is used for a number of services such as iCloud storage and purchasing apps from the Mac app store. An AppleID isn't required to create an account, however, so you should be able to skip the 'create an AppleID step'.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely skip the Sign in / Create AppleID step, simply click the "Skip" button in the lower right corner of the window:

[image]

You can always sign in and/or create an AppleID after the fact.  After skipping the step in the initial setup you WILL be prompted to create an account, however this is a local user account that will be used to administer your Mac, this is in no way attached to AppleID aside from enabling the option to "allow AppleID to reset this password".

Comment: +many points for the proper use of a black stick to focus attention on the **skip** button.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass it in command line?